# Can't install json gem on Windows7

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm running Windows7 and I've having great difficulty installing the json gem.  The error I'm getting hasn't been addressed anywhere.  I have installed DevKit through the RailsInstaller and when I run gem install json I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Gavin>gem install json
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:161: warning: overriding commands for target `install-so'
Makefile:160: warning: ignoring old commands for target `install-so'
Makefile:162: *** missing separator.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin;/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin;/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Anyone have any ideas what may be going on here?

Comment: maybe there's a different make in your path?

Answer (score 0):

i suppose your devkit-folder is in the path ? Otherwise try it with "gem install json_pure" instead. See this article that explains why http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/a/The-Json-Gem.htm